# Printing Paper Size not proper

Tags: jquery, html, printing

I have been working on a document builder where we need to add page and can set paper size. I have been setting paper size (letter : 11.00 X 8.50, legal : 14.00 X 8.50, A4: 8.30 X 11.70) width X height respectively.

But when comes to printing no page format is coming proper. Few text of the next page also appears on first page and moves on respectively.

Sorry can find the accurate word to express the situation.

Below is my code for printing :

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnPrintNote', function () {    
var divContents = $(".xmlResult").html();
var divForPrinting = $('<div></div>').attr("class", "printingDiv");

divForPrinting.append(divContents).find('hr').remove();
var html = divForPrinting.html();

var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
html += "<script>" +
            "window.onload = function() {" +
                "window.print();" +
            "};" +
         "</script>";
printWindow.document.write(html);
printWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Techidiot I have updated my Question. Please review.